# How can I plot a bar graph of average values in months

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Assume I have a dataset `data` imported from CSV

| Posted.On | Rent |
| --- | --- |
| 5/18/2022 | 220 |
| 5/04/2022 | 260 |
| 6/09/2022 | 150 |

I wish to plot a bar graph of the average rent value for each month. In the example above, it should show 2 bars May and June, with the value for bar May to be 240 and the value for June at 150.

I have tried

`ggplot(data, aes(x=(month(as.Date(Posted.On)))), y = mean(Rent)) + geom_bar()`

but to no avail

Comment: Something like `ggplot(data, aes(x = month(as.Date(Posted.On)), y = Rent)) + geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")` should do the trick, as long as the dates are in the correct format (not m/d/Y as in your example)

Comment: Adding to Allan: Your dates aren't in standard format. So you have to set the format, i.e. use `month(as.Date(Posted.On, "%m/%d/%Y"))`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend manipulating your data before `ggplot`, also if you have a aesthetic `y` to use `geom_col()`,

```
data <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Posted.On, ~Rent,
    "5/18/2022",  220L,
    "5/04/2022",  260L,
    "6/09/2022",  150L
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Posted.On = lubridate::mdy(Posted.On))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  group_by(month = month(Posted.On)) %>%
  summarise(Rent = mean(Rent)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y = Rent)) +
  geom_col()
```